# Multiple-select question on chinese remainder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, relations, chinese-remainder-theorem

Which of the following integers can be written in the form $595m+252n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers.

1. $1$
2. $5$
3. $7$
4. $63$

Now can we use the Chinese remainder theorem in this?

I don't know how could we apply that here.

Please help.

Comment: note that $252=7\times4\times9$ and $595=7\times5\times17$

Comment: You can probably use the chinese remainder theorem for this exercise, but for me the most natural choice would be to use Bézout's identity

Comment: @J.W.Tanner..so?..how to proceed with that?

Comment: $\gcd(252,595)=7$, so, by [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), the integers of the form $595m+252n$ are exactly the multiples of $7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\text{gcd}$ of $252$ and $595$ is pretty easily seen to be $7$ (see @J.W. Tanner's comment).

Then by Bezout's identity, $7$ is a linear combination of $252$ and $595$.  (To get such a linear combination, you can use the Euclidean algorithm and then work backwards.  This is called the *extended Euclidean algorithm*.)

Furthermore, if any other number could be written as a such a linear combo, it would be a multiple of $7$ (also noted by @J.W. Tanner). So, since $63$ is a multiple of $7$, we get $3.$ and $4.$ for our solutions.